# Определить вибрацию на android

Tags: android

Можно ли как нибудь определить, что на телефоне произошло событие вибрации? Не зависимо от того, какое приложение использовало вибрацию.

Comment: Попробуй усилить вибрацию, чтобы телефон со скоростью 3-4 сантиметра в секунду передвигался; добавь листенер местоположения по GPS (самый точный); и как только произойдёт изменение местоположения телефона, сразу можешь знать: телефон вибрирует. :D

Comment: А ещё кстати местоположение по высоте от центра земли сделай, вдруг телефон со стола упал. Значит точно вибрация.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В манифесте:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Вот такой `AsyncTask` получился:

```
    public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        mTextView.setText("УРАА!!! Телефон вибрирует");
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        boolean isVibration = true;
        while (isVibration){
            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(200);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/sys/class/timed_output/vibrator/enable"));
                String str = "";
                while ((str = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                    if (!str.equals("0")) isVibration = false;
                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

На моем телефоне (android 5.1, рут права) работает. Просьба: протестируйте на других устройствах.

Comment: Android 4.4.2, такой файл существует. Только, почему-то, всегда значение 0. Странно.

Comment: протестировал на android 5.0 без рут прав. Работает. Наверное это прокатывает только с 5 версии.

Comment: Там значение всегда 0. Оно только в момент вибрации меняется, на количество оставшихся миллисекунд. Приходится в отдельном потоке проверять все время пока не сработает вибрация. Только вот наверное это жрет заряд аккумулятора.

Comment: согласен. Но надо на деле всё-таки проверить.

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, это невозможно. [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29862965/detect-the-device-is-vibrating) также задан этот вопрос.

Возможно, где-то в природе и существуют какие-нибудю махинации с системными файлами, прошивками и прочим. Это нужно поискать в интернете. Не так всё просто, как кажется.